# В каких случаях вызов функции не приводит к её выполнению?

Tags: c++, функции

В каких случаях вызов функции (т.е. `func()`) не приводит к её выполнению?

Answer (score 6):

Мне известно два случая:

1. Когда вызов функции является аргументом `decltype`:

```
#include <iostream>

int func(int x)
{
    std::cout << "x is " << x << std::endl;
    return 123;
}

int main()
{
    decltype(func(555)) var;
    // Ничего не выведет в терминал
    return 0;
}
```

2. Когда вызов функции является аргументом `sizeof`:

```
#include <iostream>

int func(int x)
{
    std::cout << "x is " << x << std::endl;
    return 123;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(func(555)) << std::endl;
    // Выведет на экран 4
    return 0;
}
```

В данных случаях обьяснение простое: в этих двух примерах от функции нужно было узнать только тип возвращаемого значения, а чтобы это сделать не нужно вызывать функцию. Достаточно просто посмотреть на её обьявление.

Comment: Еще `__typeof()__` забыли

Comment: @avp Добавляйте свой ответ:)

Comment: Я такие "ответы" не люблю писать

Comment: `false && f()` + `true || f()` + `typeid( f() )` + `noexcept( f() )`. [Пример](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47abd1240ce1b531). Также `__typeof()__` не есть стандартная конструкция, а расширение некоторых компиляторов.

Comment: @wololo Добавьте свой ответ.

Comment: оба случая - это т.н. не вычисляемый (не выполняемый?) контекст. Например, такой же контекст будет в noexcept. Во всех этих случаях нет вызова функции, поэтому данный ответ вряд ли подходит.